# Pytorch DataParallel with custom model

Tags: pytorch, torch, pytorch-lightning

I want to train model with multiple gpu's. I'm using following code

```
model = load_model(path)
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
  print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
  # dim = 0 [30, xxx] -> [10, ...], [10, ...], [10, ...] on 3 GPUs
  model = nn.DataParallel(model)

model.to(device)
```

It works well except DataParallel doesn't contain functions from original model, is there a way around it? Thank you

Comment: "*DataParallel doesn't contain functions from original model*", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Ivan I am very new to ML, it's VQGan model and it contains VectorQuantizer as self.quantize attribute and it's missing when we do  "model = nn.DataParallel(model)"

Comment: Hello, since there is a tag for pytorch-lightning, would you want to check the docs for multi GPU there? https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/multi_gpu.html#distributed-modes

Comment: @NanoBit Thank you, yes model inherits pl.LightningModule

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) passed to [`nn.DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html) will end up being wrapped by the class to handle data parallelism. You can still access your model with the `module` attribute.

```
>>> p_model = nn.DataParallel(model)
>>> p_model.module # <- model
```

For instance, to access your underlying model's `quantize` attribute, you would do:

```
>>> p_model.module.quantize
```